# Xamarin Forms AudioRecorder - not finding the .ios partial class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement this solution in a project of mine and I'm having some issues.

I'm following this sample:
https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder/tree/master/Samples/Forms

The problem is that I'm using a Portable Class Library approach and the example uses Shared Project instead of PCL.

If I include the AudioPlayer.cs file in the portable class library:

```
public partial class AudioPlayer
{
}
```

in the constructor of the page i'm having some errors on this line:

```
player.FinishedPlaying += Player_FinishedPlaying;
```

It couldn't find .ios projects partial class (which has the FinishedPlaying).

Is there a way by using Portable Class Library I can do this and use the partial class with the iOS and Android projects?

I am guessing, that I may need some kind of dependency injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure you installed nuget package Plugin.AudioRecorder in all your projects. Follow instruction on their [github](https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder).

In your PCL project delete AudioPlayer.cs class. Then add interface IAudioPlayer.cs with this implemantation:

```
public interface IAudioPlayer
{
    void Play(string pathToAudioFile);
    event EventHandler FinishedPlaying;
    void Pause();
    void Play();
}
```

In your iOS project implement class RecordAudio_iOS.cs:

```
[assembly : Dependency(typeof(RecordAudio_iOS))]

namespace AudioPlayerTest.iOS
{
    public class RecordAudio_iOS : IAudioPlayer
    {
        public event EventHandler FinishedPlaying;
        private AVAudioPlayer _audioPlayer = null;

        public void Pause()
        {
            _audioPlayer?.Pause();
        }

        public void Play(string pathToAudioFile)
        {
            // Check if _audioPlayer is currently playing
            if (_audioPlayer != null)
            {
                _audioPlayer.FinishedPlaying -= Player_FinishedPlaying;
                _audioPlayer.Stop();
            }

            string localUrl = pathToAudioFile;
            _audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(localUrl));
            _audioPlayer.FinishedPlaying += Player_FinishedPlaying;
            _audioPlayer.Play();
        }

        public void Play()
        {
            _audioPlayer?.Play();
        }

        private void Player_FinishedPlaying(object sender, AVStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            FinishedPlaying?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that for Dependency you use the correct assembly Xamarin.Forms.

Then you can call in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
DependencyService.Get<IAudioPlayer>().FinishedPlaying += Player_FinishedPlaying; 
DependencyService.Get<IAudioPlayer>().Play(filePath);
```